# Bootstrap site scrolls off screen on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a website using bootstrap at: http://thecoterielondon.com/thankyou.html

On a non-mobile browser, the website seems to have a whole load of blank space off to the right of the screen. I think it is the first row that holds the social icons that is causing this, but I can't work out why it is wider than the screen.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Mark

Apparently I can't comment, so I've edited this post to say thanks to janwschaefer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the min-width set here:

```
.rowvcenter {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```